# res.json() is not a function...mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am not sure where i went wrong,when i run the code,it says error res.json(res) is not a function......

my node.js,

```
 exports.inserttopic = function (req, res) {
  var topics = new Topics(req.body);console.log(topics)
  topics.status = '1';
  topics.type = 'topics';
  var data = {};
  topics.save(function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }
    data = { status: false, error_code: 1, message: 'Unable to insert' };
    if (res) {
      data = { status: true, error_code: 0, result: res, message: 'Inserted successfully' };
    }
    res.json(data);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different variable name when you do `topics.save()` than `res`. In your code, you are overwriting the original `res` and thus do not have access to the response object.

So this is what your code would look like

```
exports.inserttopic = function (req, res) {
  var topics = new Topics(req.body);console.log(topics)
  topics.status = '1';
  topics.type = 'topics';
  var data = {};
  topics.save(function (err, mongooseResponse) { \\ Do not use res here
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    }
    data = { status: false, error_code: 1, message: 'Unable to insert' };
    if (mongooseResponse) {
      data = { status: true, error_code: 0, result: mongooseResponse, message: 'Inserted successfully' };
    }
    res.json(data);
  });
};
```